# Is there an equivalent of Kaluza-Klein for fermionic dimensions?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, fermions, spacetime-dimensions, kaluza-klein

Taking GR in $D$ dimensions, one can use the process of compactification to turn this into GR in $D-1$ dimensions coupled to a Yang-Mills field. i.e. you start with spin-2 fields and you and up with spin-2 and spin-1 fields but with the same degrees of freedom but in less dimensions.

I am looking for a process in which one can take GR in $D$ dimensions and turn this into a theory in $D-n$ dimensions coupled to fermion fields. This sounds absurd but, for example there are supersymmetry operations that turn bosons into fermions.

Or is there on the other hand some kind of no-go theorem that says this kind of process is impossible.

For example what happens if you compactify on a non-orientable surface (such as a Klein bottle) would this produce fermions?

Comment: By working just with the EH action, on dimensionally reducing you end up with spin 2, spin 1 and spin zero by a process which involves 'ignoring' one or both of the vector indices of some of the metric components, how could you get a spinor by simply ignoring one or two vector indices?

Comment: @bolbteppa I don't know. That's why I asked.